# Why is this implicit type conversion happening in this COALESCE statement?

Tags: sql-server, database, types, sqldatatypes

Why does Ceiling() change the data type to (38,0) here, losing the precision after the decimal point?

This ONLY happens with Decimal(38, X) as shown below.

Running on Microsoft SQL Server 2016

```
DECLARE @decimal2 DECIMAL(37,4) = 1.1
SELECT COALESCE(1.1,CEILING(@decimal2))
```

^this returns 1.1

```
DECLARE @decimal DECIMAL(38,4) = 1.1
SELECT COALESCE(1.1,CEILING(@decimal))
```

^this returns 1!!

Comment: Why are you wrapping with `COALESCE` here as well?

Comment: Hmm, maybe because when you ceil something like 9999999999999999999999999999999999999.1 (37 digits before and one after), which results in 10000000000000000000000000000000000000, you need that extra digit to prevent an overflow.

Comment: @larnu, This is just a test piece of code that represents a much more complicated piece of code. It was the easiest way to boil down the problem -- when you COALESCE the data type with the highest precedence is chosen and here that data type is decimal(38,0) cutting off our precision.

Comment: @stickybit, That makes a lot of sense..

Answer (score 3):

[Ceiling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) returns an integer, but it should be of the datatype that was passed in. I don't know why this particular issue is caused in the example, but you can overcome it like so:

```
DECLARE @decimal DECIMAL(38,4) = 1.1
SELECT COALESCE(@decimal,CEILING(@decimal)) --RETURNS 1
SELECT COALESCE(@decimal,CAST(CEILING(@decimal) AS DECIMAL(38,4))) --RETURNS 1.1000
```

My rule to avoid these types of issues are to always cast different datatypes to a common one.

Comment: No Ceiling actually returns the same data type that's passed in. edit (maybe this isn't quite right -- see documentation)

Comment: "Ceiling returns an integer datatype." -- The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) states otherwise: "Return values have the same type as *numeric_expression* (the input; annotation: me)."

Comment: @EvanCS added a link to the documentation

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that comment lower in the documentation. I read this "This function returns the smallest integer greater " and didn't continue reading

Comment: No worries! Also, FWIW, this is easy to 'fix' I was just curious about the behavior.

Comment: @EvanCS unfortunately without source code or someone from MS weighing in, why questions like this are rarely answered.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is (confusely) explained in the [Precision, scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) article from Microsoft Docs.
This is an extract from the article:

> The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a result precision is greater than 38, it's reduced to 38, and the corresponding scale is reduced to try to prevent truncating the integral part of a result.

Now, the confusing part would be to understand how is the precision and scale calculated. From my testing, it seems to be using the addition rules. For precision `max(s1, s2) + max(p1-s1, p2-s2) + 1` and for scale `max(s1, s2)`. But since precision would go over 38, the difference is taken from the scale to preserve the integrity of the integral part.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply due to the fact that the numeric data type can only hold 38 digits and will fill up the most significant values first so if you say 37,4 it will fill up 37 places to the left of the decimal and keep remaining one to the right.
If you put 38 to the left of the decimal there is no room for decimals regardless of what you put on the right.